# Dealing with overlapping features in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, overlapping-features

If users create a polygon feature that completely overlaps another one, like this …

[image]

… then there's no way you can select the inner feature, i.e. the one that's overlapped by the other. I'm currently using a simple `SelectFeature` like this:

```
var select = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(
  [this.annotationLayer, this.controlPointsLayer], { 
    hover: true,
    renderIntent: "temporary"
    }
);
this.map.addControl(select);
select.activate();
```

But obviously, I can only get it to select the outer feature. What is the typical way of dealing with this? **How can I make it possible for the user to select the inner feature as well?**

The simplest solution would probably be to make the outer feature only selectable within the area that's left when subtracting the inner feature – but I have no idea how to go about doing that.

Comment: You need to create a z-index (Ordering) - see http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/ordering.html

Comment: Phew, so that means I'd have to manually check *every* possible combination of features for overlaps and assign a custom z-order before loading them? Like… having a function that determines whether one feature is completely contained within another one?

Comment: z-index ordering does not work

Answer (score 10):

Few options.  Some crazier :-) than others.  The basic strategies are

- Cluster features
- Hide/move the top feature
- Send the click through the top feature

==>

1. Turn on feature clustering strategy
2. Implement your own clustering algorithm, so when a new item is added or modified, your algorithm re-runs and does a nested for-loop check and n*n(-1) checks to see what overlaps with what - then modify the feature property to setup a list of overlapping features, and when the user Clicks on the feature, display a list of features that overlap and have user select what they really wanted to click on.  Makes sense?
3. Instead of implementing feature on-click, just implement a whole map click handler.  And when user clicks, check through your layer for any intersecting features - and if there is one - display that guy's pop-up, and if there are multiple, display a prompt list like in #2 above.  If none intersect, just ignore.
4. Implement a right-click option to temporarily "hide" a feature to let you get access to the hidden feature.  As soon as next one is clicked, re-display all the hidden features
5. Similar to #4, inside the top feature's pop-up, add a menu/link item to "hide" the feature.  And proceed like in #4.
6. Similar-ish to #4/5 implement a right-click "temporary move" and click drag the feature out of the way [remember it's old spot].  Then user clicks lower feature and the top one springs back to it's original position.